# Select Rows from Excel without knowing the exact Range

Tags: excel, vb.net, select, oledb

I am trying to select some Rows from an Excel file.
Normally, I would use the Column Range (i.e. A2:A20), the problem is, this method needs to work on every Excel file, where the start of the column is always `A2`, but the end of it is always different.

Some file would have a first Column of 20 rows, some others would have 40 or 60 rows.
For this reason I can't use an exact range of cells.

Is there any way to select all cells in a Column, until last non empty row?

I'm using `OleDb` to load the data from the Excel files.

Comment: ACE.OLEDB.12 or 16 + xlsx: `$"SELECT * FROM [{sheetName}$A2:ZZ]"`. Jet.OLEDB.4.0 + xls:  `$"SELECT * FROM [{sheetName}$A2:Z65535]`. A valid range is auto-detected. Specify in the connection string whether the first row contains the header and `IMEX=1` if cells may contain mixed data types (types that may not let determine the format using the first rows).

Comment: thank you so much, it worked! can i ask you where can i find documentation about it? is this just an excel selection trick? I have been googling the whole day ($A2:Z65535)

Comment: It's not a trick, that's just the range of values determined by the internal data type. 65535 is just `ushort.MaxValue` (`0xFFFF`). ACE.OLEDB has a higher limit. You reach the max rows length before that. [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

Comment: BTW, if you've solved your problem, post the code you used as an answer.